# When to use for, while, or do-while loops/ How to start it

Tags: java

Started learning about loops and the different types today. My question is in this situation which type would i try to use? And what would be the advantage over the others? After looking over my lecture notes it seems that do-while should always be used but I'm certain that it is not the case.

Also how would I start that first one about returning a sum of the "given array." what is the given array? Is it just whatever I'm supposed to be plugging into the run arguments line?

```
 public class SumMinMaxArgs {
    // TODO - write your code below this comment.
    // You will need to write three methods:
    //
    // 1.) A method named sumArray, which will return the sum
    //     of the given array.  If the given array is empty,
    //     it should return a sum of 0.
    //
    // 2.) A method named minArray, which will return the
    //     smallest element in the given array.  You may
    //     assume that the array contains at least one element.
    //     You may use your min method defined in lab 6, or
    //     Java's Math.min method.
    //
    // 3.) A method named maxArray, which will return the
    //     largest element in the given array.  You may
    //     assume that the array contains at least one element.
    //     You may use your max method defined in lab 6, or
    //     Java's Math.max method.
    // 





    // DO NOT MODIFY parseStrings!
    public static int[] parseStrings(String[] strings) {
        int[] retval = new int[strings.length];
        for (int x = 0; x < strings.length; x++) {
            retval[x] = Integer.parseInt(strings[x]);
        }
        return retval;
    }

    // DO NOT MODIFY main!
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ints = parseStrings(args);
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sumArray(ints));
        System.out.println("Min: " + minArray(ints));
        System.out.println("Max: " + maxArray(ints));
    }
}
```

Comment: [while and do while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) and [for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). Read the description, you will see that one is pretty different in his logic. Another is mostly made to iterate ("mostly" because you can do what you want with it in the end)

Comment: When you are sure how many times you want to run a loop , it is better to use a  for loop and when you don't know how many times you want to run a loop but you know the condition where to terminate it , it is better to use a while loop.  do while is used when you want to run the loop atleast once.

Comment: We are not here to do your homework. Please attempt at it first before asking a specific question. Read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla if I want to iterate X time, I can do `int i = 0; while( i++ < X )` or use a `for(int i = 0; i < X; ++i)`, that not the point.

Comment: @AxelH  , I know they both are equivalent. But I have read it many times that it is good practice to use like that.

Comment: @BhawandeepSingla and you can do `for(; condition;)` which is exactly the same as `while(condition)`.

Answer (score 1):

All three forms have exactly the same expressive power. What you use in a certain situation depends on style, convention, and convenience. This is much like you can express the same meaning with different english sentences.

That said, do - while is mostly used when the loop should run at least once (i.e. the condition is checked only after the first iteration).

for is mostly used when you are iterating over some collection or index range.

Answer (score 0):

The four kinds of loops supported in Java:

1. C-style **for** loop: `for (int i = 0 ; i < list.size() ; ++i) { ... }` when you want to access the index of some kind of list or array directly, or to do an operation multiple times.
2. **foreach** loop, when you want to iterate over a collection, but don't care about the index: `for (Customer c : customers) { ... }`
3. **while** loop: `while (some_condition) { ... }` when some code must executed as long as the condition is true. If the condition is false to start with, the code inside the block (i.e. inside the brackets) will never be executed.
4. **do while** loop: `do { statement1; } while (condition);` will execute *statement1* even if the condition is false to begin with, but it will do so only once.

Comment: **1.** is called the _for statement_ and **2.** could be called _enhanced for statement_ or simply _for statement_ too. Technicly, there are not loops even if they do provide the same behavior. [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: I would call them the "1. Please, if possible, avoid this ugly statement" and "2. Please consider `Stream.forEach()`" if the block has a single statement in it.

Comment: I forgot to mention that all of these statements can be rewritten using only `while`. Typically in languages that don't have do-while, one can do `func(); while (cond) { func(); }`

Comment: Not sure if you are joking or not here ... `Stream` are not made to execute big logic ... so don't compare _for statement_ and a this. And a classic _for statement_ is probably the most used statement in J2SE ... not sure where you learn that but I really hope you are jocking

Comment: @AxelH just what is your _technical_ definition of a loop, and how does either form of `for` statement supposedly not qualify as one?

Comment: @KevinAnderson "_The for statement provides a compact way to iterate over a range of values. Programmers often refer to it as the "for loop" because of the way in which it repeatedly loops until a particular condition is satisfied_" from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). I did made a typo in my statement, I didn't mean there where not loop but was not called loop. because this is not a _for loop_ or a _ while loop_ but statements.